# In shell, how to extract the digit among a string

Tags: shell

In fact, I'd like to use regex to extract the **seconds** of `Total Execution time:` in shell. And someone could help me out of this?

Here is the target string:

```
Val Loss:   20.032490309035197
Val Accuracy:   0.13
SystemML Statistics:
Total elapsed time:     80.698 sec.
Total compilation time:     1.325 sec.
Total execution time:       79.373 sec.
Number of compiled MR Jobs: 0.
Number of executed MR Jobs: 0.
Cache hits (Mem, WB, FS, HDFS): 141449/0/0/2.
Cache writes (WB, FS, HDFS):    22097/0/0.
Cache times (ACQr/m, RLS, EXP): 0.151/0.024/0.285/0.000 sec.
HOP DAGs recompiled (PRED, SB): 0/1802.
HOP DAGs recompile time:    1.649 sec.
Functions recompiled:       1.
Functions recompile time:   0.006 sec.
Paramserv func number of workers:   1.
Paramserv func total gradients compute time:    38.000 secs.
Paramserv func total aggregation time:  29.604 secs.
Paramserv func model broadcasting time: 0.008 secs.
Paramserv func total batch slicing time:    0.000 secs.
Total JIT compile time:     20.714 sec.
Total JVM GC count:     228.
Total JVM GC time:      3.195 sec.
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I tried with _.*[ \t]([\d]+.?[\d]*).*_ and it extracts all the digit. But I wonder if there is another way to capture directly the digit that I want.

Comment: So you want to output `79.373` ?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` command:

```
awk '/Total execution time:/{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

```
79.373
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Additionally, what does _$(NF-1)_ mean here?

Comment: `NF` indicates last field and `(NF-1)` is last but one field. `$(NF-1)` prints value of last-1 field